# How to convert a PNG image to boundries (for circle) [pygame]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

How can I convert a PNG file that I load in my code *(for `pygame`)* convert to boundaries for circle?

I have the following image *(`png`)*:

[image: Maze]

And I am using `jpeg` file as a white background.

I mean, how can I prevent the circle from going in the PNG image? The circle moves left, right, up, down with arrows keys.

My code:

```
import pygame

def main1():
    width, height = 600, 600
    posx, posy = 300, 300
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    velocity = (0, 0)
    done = False
    pygame.display.update()
    bg = pygame.image.load("maze1.png")
    bg1 = pygame.image.load("maze2.jpeg")
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        screen.blit(bg1, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            posx += 3
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            posy -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            posx -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            posy += 3
        cir = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 200, 240), (posx,posy), 10)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   pygame.init()
   main1()
   pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Check out how [pixel perfect collision detection with masks](http://renesd.blogspot.de/2017/03/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-in.html) works. This can be difficult to implement. I tried to create a Worms-like prototype once, but the movement on the pixel perfect terrain wasn't satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - it turns out that what you want is a bit more complicated than what you are trying there.

Pygame has pixel-collision detection in one function, which is "pygame.sprite.collide_mask". Trying to do pixel verification yourself with Python code checking the pixels with `image.get_at` to check for transparent pixels would be too slow - a pure Python loop through the pixels could be thousands of times slower than code that checks that in native code. Which means you have to use `pygame.sprite.collide_mask`.

The problem with that function is that it only works with image masks - and they have to be attached to a sprite object, which also has to have a valid "rectangle" attribute.  (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

The bad part is that you have to create all those things properly. The good part is that you can have some extra benefits from having Sprite objects in your code - like encapsulate some logic, and the "posx" and "posy" coordinates themselves. I kept the separate variables so you can come up with the best way you will want to do that.

Another bit of bad news is that, despite being theoretically ok, and working "quite well", there are corner cases with the mask-collsion detection. You will notice when running these examples tha when you run into a corner, you may get stuck. I tried to mitigate that with another "look ahead" step inside the collision detection function - it felt a bit better for me, but the moving circle can get stuck sometimes .

Anyway, there goes all the code:

```
"""
Author: Muhammad Nouman
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673808/how-to-convert-png-image-to-boundries-for-circle-pygame

"""
import pygame


class GameObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(image)

    def can_move(self, delta_pos, wall_map, count=1):
        old_pos = self.rect.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + delta_pos[0]
        self.rect.centery = self.rect.centery + delta_pos[0]
        result = bool(pygame.sprite.collide_mask(self, wall_map))
        if count:
            result &= not self.can_move(delta_pos, wall_map, count - 1)
        self.rect.center = old_pos
        return not result


def main1():
    width, height = 600, 600
    posx, posy = 300, 300
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    velocity = (0, 0)
    done = False
    pygame.display.update()
    bg = pygame.image.load("maze1.png")
    bg = pygame.transform.rotozoom(bg, 0, width / bg.get_width())
    bg1 = pygame.image.load("maze2.jpeg")
    character_image = pygame.Surface((20,20), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.draw.circle(character_image, (255, 200, 240, 255), (10, 10), 10)

    character = GameObject(character_image)
    character.rect.center = (posx, posy)

    tiled_maze = GameObject(bg)

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        screen.fill((255, 255,255))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if character.can_move((3, 0), tiled_maze):
                posx += 3
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            if character.can_move((0, -3), tiled_maze):
                posy -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if character.can_move((-3, 0), tiled_maze):
                posx -= 3
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            if character.can_move((0, 3), tiled_maze):
                posy += 3
        character.rect.center = ((posx, posy))
        screen.blit(character.image, character.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   pygame.init()
   main1()
   pygame.quit()
```

So, just to give a general idea: "masks" are simplified versions of images pygame can create that mark which pixels does contain something vs which pixels are fully transparent. They are created from images. The `collide_mask` method requires a Sprite object, that has a `rect` and a `mask` attribute - the `rect` contains the sprite position  on the game field, and the  `mask` is the mask created from the image.

The maze can be made to be a single sprite covering all the field (also, it had to be scaled down to fit your screen size - I made it with a call to `...rotozoom`. SInce it already contains transparency,it is all set (also, note that if you are to have a solid color background, there is no need for a second image - you can use the `fill` method of surfaces).

Now, the "circle" character has to have an image - so I spend some lines creating an in memory surface, and drawing a circle to it, and use this surface as the image for the "circle" sprite.

Since our sprite has to have a class on its own, I aded he colsiion detection logic as a method there - it basically takes a "future offset" when the sprite is to be moved, and the second sprite - in this case, always the maze. It "simulates" the new position, and check if  "self"  (i.e. the circle sprite) would be colliding with the "other sprite" mask in that position. If so, the `if`statements in the game logic prevent the position from being updated. (tweaking these if statements a bit may get you a better experience, preventing "sticky" corners as they exist in the current maze).

All in all, I hope you can understand what was done here, and that you can improve on this code for a better use experience.

Comment: Its good but the circle stuck in the maze _( when it touches it )_. Any solution for that?

Comment: Dude , the circle stuck too hard.

Comment: yep - there is something in the algorithm of "checking if I can go there, and only then go" that is faulty - since it should always be possible to step back the same way one went into there. Maybe keeping a list of the last positions the circle had been, and always white-list these as possible places to go would be a suitable workaround.